# Is there a quick way to draw a curved line with thickness that changes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am curious to see if there's a quick way to draw a curved line with thickness that changes in illustrator, like this sample:

[image]

Also, is there a way to apply this to an outlined stroke?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the path and set:

- Weight
- Cap: round
- Profile: triangle
- Flip Along: start or end

[image]

To apply this type of path in a shape, make an **Art Brush** with the described path and stroke the shape with that brush:

[image: brush]

[image: brush on a shape]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :) Helped a lot

Comment: If I may ask, is there a way to apply something like this to an outlined stroke? (or turn an outlined stroke into a path again?

Comment: Answer updated.